# Can I log the data from my methods at each test step node in the Cucumber Extent Report?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

```
public void addMakerUserNameInputField() {
        System.out.println("Adding user name input field.");
        driver.findElement(usernameInputField).sendKeys(correctMaker1Username);
        Hook.logInfo("User name:: " + correctMaker1Username);
    }

public void addMakerPasswordInputField() {
        System.out.println("Adding password input field.");
        driver.findElement(passwordInputField).sendKeys(correctMaker1Password);
        Hook.logInfo("Password:: " + correctMaker1Password);
    }
```

Above methods are from Login.java file.

```
@AfterStep
public static void addingReportInfo(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
        stepTestIndex += 1;
        if (!scenario.isFailed()) {
            test.createNode(StepDetails.stepName)
                    .log(Status.PASS, "Test step passed.");
        }
}

public static void logInfo(String message) {
        if (test != null) {
            test.log(Status.INFO, message);
        }
    }
```

These are from Hook.java file.

At cucumber html extent report, it is currently logging at the top of all test steps.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi1lf.png)

What I am expecting is that I want to log the values ("User name:: " + correctMaker1Username) and ("Password:: " + correctMaker1Password) inside the relevant step nodes. Not at the top. May I know would it be possible?

I don't want to use Datatable now as I stored test data in an excel file.